# is it possible to set a texture to a different scale on the plane

Tags: texturing

is it possible to change the scale of a texture on a plane within the same plane?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can base it on your $x$ coordinate:

[image]

Keep in mind all the *Scale* input does is it multiplies the coordinates, so the below will have the exact same effect:

[image]